# kotlin OffsetDateTime format of pattern

Tags: kotlin

I am try to convert a offsetdatetime to a specific format,  but i have a problem

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-12-27T15:49:08Z")
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM YYYY, h:mm:ss"))
```

and it print one year more

```
lun. 27 dic. 2022, 3:49:08
```

what is the reason?

thanks a lot

Comment: What is your locale? (What does `java.util.Locale.getDefault()` return?) With `en_GB`, your code gives the correct year (`Mon 27 Dec 2021, 3:49:08`).

Comment: the command return me es_CO

Comment: ok, I thought this was certainly an issue with the Locale you use. But @gidds answer seems to be the correct one. So deleted mine.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha It turns out that this _is_ affected by the locale — but only indirectly. (Like you, I thought that was the main issue — until I ran a few tests myself, and checked the docs… Nothing is ever as simple as it appears :-)

Comment: Yeah, what a tricky business we are in. This question looks simple, but here we go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're specifying the pattern `YYYY` for the year.

According to [the docs for `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), a pattern of one or more `Y`s means ‘week-based year’.

That's different from the usual ‘year-of-era’, which you get from a pattern of one or more *lower-case* `y`s.

The difference is explained in [this question](/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year). Basically, if the year starts in the middle of a week, it treats that entire week as falling either in the previous year or the following year.

The exact calculation will depend indirectly upon the locale, as that controls which day the week starts on. (I don't fully understand all the details, but I think it's mediated by the [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class. However it works, it can cause the last few days of 2021 to be treated as part of 2022, as this question demonstrates.)

In any case, it looks like your real problem is using a week-based year number when you just want the normal calendar year! So, simply change your pattern to `"EEE dd MMM yyyy, h:mm:ss"`, and you should get the expected result:

```
lun. 27 dic. 2021, 3:49:08
```